# Error in the book Graph Theory: Calculate this determinant/characteristic polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, determinant, characteristic-polynomial

In the book "Graph Theory" - by Bondy and Murty exercise 1.1.22 b) ii) wants me to prove that
$$det(J-(1+\lambda)I_n) = (1+\lambda-n)(1+\lambda)^{n-1}$$ where $J$ is the $n$ x $n$ matrix consisting only of $1$'s.

I think this is wrong by a factor of $(-1)^n$. This part of the exercise exists essentially only as a step to calculate the eigenvalues of a complete graph. For the eigenvalues the sign of the characteristic polynomial does not matter. But to me that doesn't change the fact that what they want you to show is incorrect. Can someone confirm this is in fact an error, and I'm not just making a mistake in calculating the determinant?

Comment: You are not making a mistake, indeed a factor of $(-1)^n$ is missing.

Comment: The determinant you mention is in fact incorrect by a factor of $(-1)^{n-1}$, the relation is correct for odd $n$.

Comment: @PierreCarre The example in the answer by kipf seems to indicate that the relation is wrong for odd $n$, and I came to the same conclusion by row transformations. Could you expand why you think it is the other way around?

Comment: @leon.fuchsler I just plugged it into wolfram, but I must have made some mistake because I now observe the same as you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $n=1$, \begin{align*}
\det(J - (1+\lambda)I_1) = \det(-\lambda) &= -\lambda, \text{ but} \\
(1+\lambda-1)(1+\lambda)^{1-1} &= \lambda.
\end{align*}
So yes, the given formula is wrong.